# javascript regular expression to match url

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a URL that starts with `/user/` and ends with any number and slash.

example:

```
/user/345/
```

I tried `/user/\d{3}`, but the interpreter gives me an error at `\d`.

```
if (request.url == '/') {
    absPath = './public/index.html';
    serveStatic(response, cache, absPath);
} else if (request.url.match(/user/\d{3})) {}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: My guess would be to use delimiters `/`. Which means you'll need to escape yours : `/\/user\/\d+\//`

Comment: Trailing slash - yes or no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make trailing slash optional:

```
/\/user\/\d{3}\/?/
```

or

```
/\/user\/[0-9]{3}\/?/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "/user/345/";
alert(str.match(/\/user\/\d+\//g) != null);
```

without the last slash:

```
alert(str.match(/\/user\/\d+/g) != null);
```

Comment: this worked but what if I wanted to match "/user/345"... without the slash?

Comment: Then just remove the final \/ from the regexp.  Or add a question mark just after it if you want it to be optional.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a backslash

```
request.url.match("/user/\\d{3}")
```